# Branching of $SU\left(5\right)$ under $SU\left(2\right)\times SU\left(3\right)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, branching-rules

In the context of branching rules, what is the meaning of the projection matrix, and how/what do I use it for?

For instance, for the branching of $SU\left(5\right)$ under $SU\left(2\right)\times SU\left(3\right)$, I am told that the projection matrix is 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$